# How to change access to the values of a field of type address?

Tags: apex, soql, address

in a custom object I created a field of type `Address`. Now I want to access the values of `Street`, `Postal code`, `Latitude` and `Longitude` but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the name of the custom field is `Custom_Address__c` you could access to those fields adding `Street__s`, `PostalCode__s`, `Latitude__s`, `Longitude__s` as suffix:

```
Custom_Object__c record = new Custom_Object__c();
record.Custom_Address__Street__s = 'something';
record.Custom_Address__PostalCode__s = '363001';
record.Custom_Address__Latitude__s = 41.902782;
record.Custom_Address__Longitude__s = 12.496366;
```

[Documentation - Apex Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.caf_dev_guide.meta/caf_dev_guide/caf_dev_examples_apex.htm)

Comment: And here's a link to [the Custom Address Fields Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.244.0.caf_dev_guide.meta/caf_dev_guide/caf_dev_guide.htm) if you want to go a bit more in-depth.

Comment: @DerekF Added the link to the answer, thanks!